# Loading multiple images from the webservice faster

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest, nsurlcache

I want to load multiple images from the JSON webservice to my app. These images serve as thumbnails to a "Store" in my app. So when the user clicks a button to go to the "Store", a request is being made. And this request is repeated every time the user clicks the button.

Now there is no problem here, but the problem arises when the data in JSON multiplies in quantity. Before, we are loading only 5 images. Now, we are loading at least 18 images. These could pose a real problem when the images multiplied to 100 or more.

I am contemplating in using `NSURLCache` to cache the images, but how will I know if there is an update to the images? Say a new image is added, or the current image is no longer being used? Can anyone give me any ideas on what is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

You can load multiple images from Webservices using SDWebImage From https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage
Read **how to use it** in intruction like bellow

- you need to first right click on your project name:->add files to  yourProject-> selected SDWebImageproject and add them

NOTE:- please do not check copy option

- now click on project name in Your xcode going to build phases:->target dependencies:-> click on  + button and add SDWebimage ARC
- now select link binary with library click  + button add libSDWebimageARC.a and again  click  + and add imageIO.framework and also add libxml2.dylib thats it
- going to Build setting:->other link flag:-> add -ObjC
- and header search path add this three item

  1      /usr/include/libxml2

  2     "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include"

  3     "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include"

you can impliment code like this :-
`#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>`

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];


            UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite] autorelease];
            activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
            activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
            [activityIndicator startAnimating];


            [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrlSting]
                      placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload
                               success:^(UIImage *image) { [activityIndicator stopAnimating];[activityIndicator removeFromSuperview]; }
                               failure:^(NSError *error) {  [activityIndicator stopAnimating];[activityIndicator removeFromSuperview]; }];

            [imageView addSubview:activityIndicator];


            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
            imageView.tag = 1;
            imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

now build and run its working like smoothly cheers.... :)

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll study this first and see if it will help me.

Comment: ok its very simple you can impliment in your project by read how to use at https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage and follow step as says